# DIY Remote for Fog Machine?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a fog machine, and I want to make it wirelessly dispense fog. It came with a remote I can use to control it from a distance away, however it has been lost and I do not know where it is.

I was planning to make my own remote, although I do not really know where to start. The machine has a manual button you can use to dispense fog, although it is an inconvenient to manually press it every time someone comes to the door. I know I can take off the button and rewire the wires connected to it to a switch and use it that way, however this is not preferred. This brings me to my question:

Are there any RC/wireless buttons with simple controllers that when pressed, simply allow current to flow? This would work well for what I'm trying to do, however I do not know where to start and what would be the best. Also, a range of at least 10 feet is wanted.

Comment: Small appliances are off-topic here; please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of devices that will meet your requirements. On the more-expensive, extremely long range side would be replacement garage door opener devices. I have one that wires into my existing inside door button (think doorbell switch) and allows the new remote to work like the old ones, but with greater security and flexibility.

I suspect that is more than you need. On the lower end of things, but no less applicable are keyfob remotes and receivers. Use those terms in your favorite search engine to see plenty of choices.

[Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1095) has a seven dollar (US) item that can control four circuits. Unfortunately you can't get a single circuit of that type for one-fourth of the price.

[image: keyfob remote]

For this particular item, you have to purchase the [receiver](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1097) separately at about US$5, not too pricey.

[image: receiver image]

I have purchased in a past a chinese version of this type of device. A few bucks get both the transmitter and receiver, although the receiver requires 12vdc to operate.

Many options abound, easily managed, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I saw this when I was researching the topic... But how exactly do I wire it? And what would I use for a power source?

Comment: For your application, you'd find the circuit to which the existing switch is connected. Consider that switch to have an in and an out. Connect one lead from this receiver (common) to one side of the switch in the fogger. Connect the other lead from this receiver (A, B, C, or D) to the other side of the switch. If the original switch is on, the remote does nothing. If the switch is off, the remote turns it on with a press of the button, or turns it off again. Ideally, you should be able to locate a ground and power internal to the fogger that would provide the 5v necessary to run the receiver.

Comment: If you can't find an internal 5v source (no greater than 6v per the web site), you'd have to add another wire to the fogger, perhaps a 5v wall wart power supply, as these devices use very little electricity. I don't particularly like this unit, as the pinouts are vague and may be inappropriate to your project. The ones I've used are cheaper, include the receiver with the remote and use relays for switching, eliminating guesswork. Here's one with relays: https://www.miniinthebox.com/12v-2-channel-wireless-remote-control-relay-module-with-remote-controller-dc28v-ac250v_p1636343.html?currency=USD

Comment: So would Vin go to the +5v port or Vt?

Comment: I am not comfortable with the spec sheet for the Adafruit products. I was not able to figure out how one would break a circuit using this item. It appears in their video that it's a common ground type of circuit, which differs from your requirements. The mini in the box site, on the other hand, uses ordinary relays, allowing for clear switching use. Both were provided as illustrative of possible solutions.

Comment: @fred_dot_u: you can hook a relay to the adafruit thing if it makes it simpler/safer in your mind